# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when reading file

Tags: c, string, file, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a simple project to read a `input.txt` text file and show some basic statistics about it. The file is supposed to be about the entrance on a company building. That's how the file is:

```
1 ; Visitor ; 10 ; 19 ; 2
2 ; 1 ; Worker ; 8 ; 0
3 ; 2 ; Director ; 12 ; 19
4 ; 5 ; Worker ; 18 ; 22
5 ; Visitor ; 8 ; 0 ; 3
```

> Format is = ID ; Companions(if employee) ; Type ; Entrance Time ; Exit Time ; Services(if Visitor)

I got the program to read the file correctly (i guess), it reads the first worker correctly, but when it gets to the second one it reads the ID and suddenly exits with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

[image: example of error]

I'd really appreciate if someone with more knowledge could help since i have no idea what's happening, and other questions with the same error didn't help.

Here's the code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

char * removeSpaces(char *line) {
    int counter = 0,i=0;

    while (line[i]!='\0'){
        if (line[i] == ' '){
            i++;
        } else{
            line[counter] = line[i];
            counter++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return(line);
    line[counter] = '\0';
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    char field[30];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    bool flag = false;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,counter=0; //variables to count on loops

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("%s", line);
        if(strstr(line, "Worker") != NULL) { //determine the entrance type
            line = removeSpaces(line);

            printf("\nWORKER READ\n");
            i = 0;
            while(line[i] != ';'){ //Read ID
                field[i] = line[i]; //saves the content of the field (all between ';')
                i++;
            }
            field[i] = '\0';
            printf("\nID: ");
            for(i=0;field[i] != '\0';i++){
                printf("%c",field[i]);
            }
            //memset(field,0,strlen(field));
            i = 0; j = 0;
            while(flag != true){ //Read Companions
                if(line[i] == ';'){
                    flag = true; //keeps skipping the string till it finds the right field
                }
                if(flag == true){
                    j = i+1;
                    while(line[j] != ';'){
                        field[k] = line[j]; //saves the content of the field (all between ';')
                        j++; k++;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            field[k] = '\0';
            printf("\nCOMPANIONS: ");
            for(i=0;field[i] != '\0';i++){
                printf("%c",field[i]); //prints what the number of companions read
            }
            //memset(field,0,strlen(field));
            i = 0; j = 0; k = 0; flag = false;
            while(flag != true){ //Read Type
                if(line[i] == ';'){
                    counter++;
                    if(counter == 2){
                        flag = true; //keeps skipping the string till it finds the right field
                    }
                }
                if(flag == true){
                    j = i+1;
                    while(line[j] != ';'){
                        field[k] = line[j]; //saves the content of the field (all between ';')
                        j++; k++;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            field[k] = '\0';
            printf("\nTIPO: ");
            for(i=0;field[i] != '\0';i++){
                printf("%c",field[i]); /prints the type of entrance read
            }
            //memset(field,0,strlen(field));
            i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;  flag = false; counter = 0;
            while(flag != true){ //Read Entrance Time
                if(line[i] == ';'){
                    counter++;
                    if(counter == 3){
                        flag = true; //keeps skipping the string till it finds the right field
                    }
                }
                if(flag == true){
                    j = i+1;
                    while(line[j] != ';'){
                        field[k] = line[j]; //saves it
                        j++; k++;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            field[k] = '\0';
            printf("\nENTRANCE: ");
            for(i=0;field[i] != '\0';i++){
                printf("%c",field[i]);
            }
            i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;  flag = false; counter = 0;
            while(flag != true){ //Read Exit Time
                if(line[i] == ';'){
                    counter++;
                    if(counter == 4){
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                if(flag == true){
                    j = i+1;
                    while(line[j] != ';'){
                        field[k] = line[j];
                        j++; k++;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            field[k] = '\0';
            printf("\nSAIDA: ");
            for(i=0;field[i] != '\0';i++){
                printf("%c",field[i]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");

            i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;  flag = false;
            memset(field,0,strlen(field));
        } else if(strstr(line, "Director") != NULL){
            //TODO
        } else if(strstr(line, "Visitor") != NULL){
            //TODO
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Segmentation fault" is your cue to pop this into the debugger and see what lead up to that point.

Comment: This is a lot of code and it's littered with meaningless variable names like `i`, `j` and so on. When writing code, *especially* for posting here, please take the time to make variable names communicate your intent.

Comment: I don't know how to work a debugger yet, but thanks for the tip, I'll try to search how to use it in Geany!
`i`, `j` and `k` are simple counter variables, to run in loops, i sincerely don't know how to add more detail in their name. I can try to add more comments to make the code more readable i guess.

Comment: Short variable names need to have very small scopes in order to avoid ambiguity. Using `i` within the context of a single `for` or `while` loop is fine (e.g. `for (int i =0; ..)`) but declaring it at the start of your function is hugely problematic. The broader the scope, the more descriptive your name must be. Global variables for example, where they're unavoidable, must have extremely clear names.

Comment: As for the debugger, that's an *essential tool* when writing C code, so if you don't know how to use it yet, you have a perfect opportunity here to try one out. A debugger will  show you the state of any variables leading up to that crash. "Segmentation fault" often comes about when you de-reference an invalid pointer, be it uninitialized, NULL, or something you've previously de-allocated and has now been scrambled by other parts of your code.

Comment: `fgets()` would at least be a more portable alternative to `getline()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sscanf` could be used to parse the values from `line`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    char id[30];
    char companions[30];
    char type[30];
    char entrance[30];
    char depart[30];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("%s", line);
        if(strstr(line, "Worker") != NULL) { //determine the entrance type
            printf("\nWORKER READ\n");
            if ( 5 == sscanf ( line, "%29s ; %29s ; %29s ; %29s ; %29s"
            , id, companions, type, entrance, depart)) {
                printf("\nID: %s", id);
                printf("\nCOMPANIONS: %s", companions);
                printf("\nTIPO: %s", type);
                printf("\nENTRANCE: %s", entrance);
                printf("\nSAIDA: %s", depart);
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            else {
                printf ( "problem parsing Worker\n");
            }

        } else if(strstr(line, "Director") != NULL){
            //TODO
        } else if(strstr(line, "Visitor") != NULL){
            //TODO
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying this eliminates the segfault?

Comment: Did you identify where the original segfault was?

Comment: wow, thanks a LOT user3121023, i guess that's what experience looks like since i didn't even know `sscanf` existed...
It also didn't segfault on me with this code, it's hard to believe it could be done so simple.

Comment: @Skepller, you still need to understand why your code faulted. Failure to track that down would be a major lost opportunity to learn.

Comment: I see what you mean, since i don't know actually what went wrong in my original code, but i don't know if it's worth going deeper in it since i was unintentionally really over-complicating it! Since i, now, learned it can be done SO much simpler, i wont be returning to write like that anyway...

Comment: @user3121023, nice catch.

Comment: @Skepller, it's important to understand your error tendencies. You are always going to make mistakes when you write code. Knowing where your blind spots are will help you to be more careful when writing that kind of code. Iterating through memory is a very common programming task. Learning to avoid over-complicating things is also good, but even the simplest code can quickly overrun a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

While I recommend `sscanf` or `fscanf` over writing complicated parsing code, it's also good for your coding skills to learn how to write parsers. After adjusting your code to use `fgets` instead of `getline` so that I could get it to compile, I hit a fault in this loop:

```
while ( flag != true )
{ //Read Type
    if ( line[i] == ';' ) // <<<< Fault when i = 2488
    {
        counter++;
        if ( counter == 2 )
        {
            flag = true; //keeps skipping the string till it finds the right field
        }
    }
    if ( flag == true )
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while ( line[j] != ';' )
        {
            field[k] = line[j]; //saves the content of the field (all between ';')
            j++; k++;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

You're incrementing i without reference to the length of the actual line, so at some point you are accessing a memory address that you do not own.

You should enable all warnings when you compile your code. Your compiler should be warning you of some of your mistakes. One of the important ones you should be seeing is "Unreachable code..." at line 27 in your `removeSpaces` function:

```
return(line);
line[counter] = '\0'; // This never executed.
```

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fgets.html